# Add string to page title if post in specific category

Tags: pages, title

Can someone please help me add a string to WP page title depending on category of a post ?

I did this with post title (code below) however I want to extend it to page title.

```php
function recipe_titles ($title, $id=null) {
    if (in_category ('recipes', $id)) {
    $title = "Recept: " .$title;
    }
    return $title;

    }
add_filter ('the_title', 'recipe_titles',10,2);
```

Comment: You mean, the title in the `title` tag as in `<title>here</title>`? And is this for single post pages, i.e. posts in the `post` type? Also, the `Recept:` - did you mean, `Recipe:` ?

Comment: Yes - I want to dynamically change the page title of WP post depending on post category. I managed to do that with post title with this code:

Comment: function recipe_titles ($title, $id=null) {
    if (in_category ('recipes', $id)) {
    $title = "Recept: " .$title;
    }
    return $title;
    }
add_filter ('the_title', 'recipe_titles',10,2);

Comment: Site is Bosnian and it uses "Recept:" instead of English "Recipe"

Comment: I've posted an answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the title in the `title` tag as in `<title>here</title>` on *single* post pages, then you might want to use the [`single_post_title` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/single_post_title/) to prepend the string in question to the page title. E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'recipe_single_post_title', 10, 2 );
function recipe_single_post_title( $title, $post ) {
    if ( in_category( 'recipes', $post ) ) {
        return "Recept: $title";
    }

    return $title;
}
```

But there are other filters you can try:

- If your theme supports the [automatic `<title>` tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#title-tag) (and BTW it actually should support it), e.g. in the `functions.php` file it calls `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )`, then you can use the [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) or [`document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title/) filter. E.g. Using the former:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'recipe_page_title_parts' );
  function recipe_page_title_parts( $title ) {
      if ( is_single() && in_category( 'recipes' ) ) {
          $title['title'] = 'Recept: ' . $title['title'];
      }

      return $title;
  }
  ```
- If (for whatever reasons) your theme is hard-coding the `<title>` tag into the header template (`header.php`), then you can use the [`wp_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title_parts/) or [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) filter. E.g. Using the former:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'wp_title_parts', 'recipe_page_title_parts2' );
  function recipe_page_title_parts2( $title ) {
      if ( is_single() && in_category( 'recipes' ) ) {
          $title[0] = 'Recept: ' . $title[0];
      }

      return $title;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! My name is Daniel - nice to meet you. Would you mind writing a short interpretation of the elements of code I do not understand ? Part 1 - In the first block of code  I shared on the top of this topic, I want to know the meaning of the following: a) Are the variables $title and $id predefined in Wordpress ? Does Wordpress fill the variable $title with post title by default ? What confuses me is - how does Wordpress know that the post title is in the $title variable ?

Comment: b) Why is it necessary to declare $id = null before writing the rest of the function ? c) what does return $title mean in human layperson language ? d) What is human layperson interpretation of this line of code: add_filter ('the_title', 'recipe_titles',10,2);  Part 2 - Is $title an array ? What is the first part of an array ? Can you please explain this code of yours : $title[0] = 'Recept: ' . $title[0];         Thank you

Comment: Hi Daniel. First off, if my answer answered your question, you can mark my answer as correct, a.k.a. accept it. Secondly, this stack/site is for WordPress-specific questions only, e.g. how to use `add_filter()`, but for example the last question (the `$title[0] = ...`) in your second comment was generic PHP/programming question. And thirdly, even if your question is WordPress-specific, please ask only one question per post - e.g. if you wanted to know about hook/action/filter A and B, then you'd post two questions.

Comment: If I make a separate post, how do I make sure you read it ? May I please have your email address ?

Comment: Well I'm not the only one who could help you here..  Remember this is a community site, so everyone can basically answer a question. Thus, just post your question, but be as detailed as possible (include your/sample code), and someone else might be able to help even if I didn't see your post. However, you should first check the relevant documentation and articles before asking a question - perhaps there's even a similar question on this stack which already had a solution you could still use even now.

Comment: [This](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) is an example resource where you can learn about WordPress hooks (actions and filters), and WordPress also has a code reference where you can learn about specific function/hook, e.g. [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for `add_filter()`. So be sure to check them out. And for generic PHP/programming questions, you can post/search on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a book, video or online course you can recommend I take  in order to learn these and similar things ?

Comment: It will take me forever if I don't get help like yours. Google does not solve my problem and it does not fit my learning style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138236/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-tbv-translation).